# Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)

Tags: numerics, polynomials, complex, algebraic-manipulation, faq

Say I want to quickly calculate $\sqrt[3]{-8}$, to which the most obvious solution is $-2$.

When I input $\sqrt[3]{-8}$ or `Power[-8, 3^-1]`, Mathematica gives the result $2 (-1)^{1/3}$. Not what I want.

When I input `Power[-8, 3^-1] // N` or `Power[-8., 3^-1]`, Mathematica gives the result $1. + 1.73205i$. While technically correct, this is messy and not always useful.

**How can I get the *real* cube root of a negative number?** Or more generally, how can I get a list of *all* valid roots?

Comment: For your first question, some day one will be able to do as below. (But not today, unless you are here.)   
``In[99] := NumericalMath`CubeRoot[-8]

Out[99] = -2``

Comment: @Daniel - Looks great, looking forward to it. Er, unless the previous 98 steps are also required :-/

Comment: Table[N[((x)^(1/3))], {x,-50,50,10}]  vs Table[N[CubeRoot[x]], {x,-50,50,10}]. This is kind of crazy

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Mathematica 9 introduces two new functions, `CubeRoot` and `Surd`, that give real-valued roots:

```
In[1]:= CubeRoot[-8]
Out[1]= -2

In[2]:= Surd[-32, 5]
Out[2]= -2
```

You can use these to plot real roots:

```
Plot[CubeRoot[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Note that these functions are undefined for complex numbers:

```
In[5]:= CubeRoot[1 + I]

CubeRoot::preal: The parameter 1+I should be real valued. >>

Out[5]= Surd[1 + I, 3]
```

and the typeset form has a small "tail" at the end of the overbar to visually distinguish them from the usual roots:

[image]

Comment: The name `Surd` stands for?

Comment: @enzotib A root containing an unresolved radical sign. From Wikipedia: _"The term surd traces back to al-Khwārizmī (c. 825), who referred to rational and irrational numbers as audible and inaudible, respectively. This later led to the Arabic word "أصم‎" (asamm, meaning "deaf" or "dumb") for irrational number being translated into Latin as "surdus" (meaning "deaf" or "mute"). Gerard of Cremona (c. 1150), Fibonacci (1202), and then Robert Recorde (1551) all used the term to refer to unresolved irrational roots."_

Comment: @flinty So the Wolfram implementation of `Surd` is at odds with the traditional and most often used definition, e.g., an unresolved irrational root?

Answer (score 57):

In general, a typical root of a negative number is complex, so you need to get rid of most roots. A nice approach would be `Root`, e.g.

```
Root[ x^3 + 8, #] & /@ Range[3]
```

> ```
> {-2, 1 - I Sqrt[3], 1 + I Sqrt[3]}
> ```

To get only real roots you can do :

```
Select[Root[ x^3 + 8, #] & /@ Range[3], Re[#] == # &]
```

> ```
> {-2}
> ```

This is a handy approach when you have roots of lower orders.

However you'd rather use `Reduce` or `Solve` for higher order roots, in this case it works like this :

```
Reduce[ x^3 + 8 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> x == -2 || x == 1 - I Sqrt[3] || x == 1 + I Sqrt[3]
> ```

```
Solve[ x^3 + 8 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2 (-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> -2 (-1)^(2/3)}}
> ```

To get only real roots one can use for example : `Reduce[x^3 + 8 == 0, x, Reals]` or `Solve[x^3 + 8 == 0, x, Reals]`.  They do almost the same, but their outputs are a bit different, respectively : in the boolean form and in the form of rules.

As a more appropriate example of what you want to do I could choose this one : `(-3)^(1/7)`. Mathematica treats variables (in general) as complex. So one gets seven roots
and there is the only one real.

```
Solve[ x^7 + 3 == 0, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -3^(1/7)}}
> ```

To get the full output one can do this :

```
points = {Re @ #, Im @ #} & /@ Last @@@ Solve[x^7 + 3 == 0, x]
```

[image]

Absolute values of the roots are the same, so they are found on the circle of a given radius (`== 3^(1/7)`) :

```
{ Equal @@ #, radius = #[[1]] } & @ Simplify @ (Norm /@ points)
```

> ```
>  {True, 3^(1/7)}
> ```

To visualize the structure of the output one makes use of `ContourPlot` of real and imaginary parts of the function `(x + I y)^7 + 3` (we  write the function explicitly in the complex form since we make plots in real domains of `x` and `y` ) :

```
GraphicsRow[{
    ContourPlot[ Re[(x + I y)^7 + 3], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
                 Epilog -> {Darker@Green, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ points, 
                 Gray, Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, radius], PointSize[0.02], Blue, Point[points]}], 

    ContourPlot[ Im[(x + I y)^7 + 3], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
                 Epilog -> {Darker@Green, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ points, 
                 Gray, Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, radius], PointSize[0.02], Blue, Point[points]}]}]
```

[image]

**Clarification**

- The blue points            --- roots
- lengths of the green lines --- absolute values of the roots
- the dashed circle          --- a set of all complex numbers `z` such that `Abs[z] == radius`

The only one real root lies on the line `y == 0`.

Comment: I would recommend using `Root[#^3 + 8&, #]& /@ Range[3]` instead of `Root[ x^3 + 8, #]& /@ Range[3]`. Using a symbol like `x` is going to cause errors when it's already defined.

Answer (score 26):

You may use a function, which gives you the "real Power":

```
rprule=(b_?Negative)^Rational[m_,n_?OddQ]:>(-(-b)^(1/n))^m;
Attributes[realPower]={Listable, NumericFunction,OneIdentity}  (* same as Power *)
realPower[b_?Negative, Rational[m_, n_?OddQ]] := (-(-b)^(1/n))^m;
realPower[x_,y_]:=Power[x,y];
realPower[x_]:=x//.rprule;
```

Then you'll get:

```
realPower[{8^(1/3),(-8)^(1/3)]
```

> {2,-2}

The "two arguments" form is needed eg. in plots:

```
Plot[realPower[x, 1/3], {x, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: Was very useful to me. +1

Answer (score 16):

In general, to get a list of all the cube roots of `-8` (or the $m$ roots of any number $n$), you can use either the the `Roots` or `Solve` or `Reduce` functions.

```
Roots[x^3 == -8, x]
(* Out[1]=  x == 2 || x == 2 (-1)^(2/3) || x == -2 (-1)^(1/3) *)
```

`Reduce` and `Solve` are perhaps more flexible because you can specify the domain that you want or leave it out for all the solutions.

```
Reduce[x^3 == 8, x]
(* Out[2]= x == 2 || x == -1 - I Sqrt[3] || x == -1 + I Sqrt[3] *)

Reduce[x^3 == 8, x, Reals]
(* Out[3]= x == 2

Solve[x^3 == 8, x]
(* Out[4]= {{x -> 2}, {x -> -2 (-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> 2 (-1)^(2/3)}} *)

Solve[x^3 == 8, x, Reals]
(* Out[5]= {{x -> 2}} *)
```

Note that the structure of the output returned for `Reduce` and `Solve` are different.

Answer (score 8):

I quite prefer `realPower[x_, r_] := Sign[x]*Abs[x]^r` myself. (A similar thing is done in the old package [`` Miscellaneous`RealOnly` ``](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6771/).) `realPower[-8, 1/3]` yields `-2`, as expected. To get *all* the real roots, [Artes's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3888) is best.

Answer (score 4):

Let us introduce a rule:

```
cubicRootRule = a_^(1/3) /; Negative[a] -> -(Abs[a])^(1/3);
```

To check it let us form a list with cubic roots of various numbers, positive and negative:

```
 lst = Table[(RandomInteger[{-16, 16}])^(1/3), {20}]

(* {(-11)^(1/3), 10^(1/3), (-10)^(1/3), 6^(1/3), (-5)^(1/3),  
  2 (-1)^(1/3), (-10)^(1/3), (-3)^(1/3), 2^(1/3), (-15)^(1/3),
  3^( 1/3), (-7)^(1/3), (-7)^(1/3), 15^(1/3), (-5)^(1/3),  
   2 (-1)^(1/3), 13^(1/3), (-13)^(1/3), 2 (-2)^(1/3), 2^(2/3) 3^(1/3)} *)
```

and apply the rule to the list:

```
lst /. cubicRootRule

(* {-11^(1/3), 10^(1/3), -10^(1/3), 6^(
 1/3), -5^(1/3), -2, -10^(1/3), -3^(1/3), 2^(1/3), -15^(1/3), 3^(
 1/3), -7^(1/3), -7^(1/3), 15^(1/3), -5^(1/3), -2, 13^(
 1/3), -13^(1/3), -2 2^(1/3), 2^(2/3) 3^(1/3)} *)
```

That's it?