# Is there an $n^{\text{th}}$ root function in Mathematica?

Tags: functions

Is there a way to find $\sqrt[n]{x}$ with *Mathematica* beside of `x^(1/n)`
as this is something different, because this is not always the same
$$(-1)^{\frac{2}{4}}=i \neq 1= \sqrt[4]{(-1)^2}$$
In the help I only found `Sqrt[x]` which is the squareroot and `CubeRoot[x]` for the cubic root.
Is there a reason that there aren't $n$-th roots implemented? (Assuming they really don't exist and I am not to stupid to find them).

I am using *Mathematica* 9.0.1 Student Edition.

Comment: Look at `Surd` it's new in `ver.9`, e.g.  `Surd[11, 5] // N` yields `1.61539`

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8

Comment: It is generally welcome to post an answer to your own question. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Actually, one of the four solutions of $\sqrt[4]{(-1)^2} = 1^{\frac{1}{4}}$ _is_ $i$.

Comment: @poorsod Do you think of $z^4=1$? that is something different (an equation), I am talking about the function, this need to be welldefined so their are no _solutions_ there are just values which are taken.

Comment: That you're using a Student Edition should be irrelevant: it has exactly the same functionality as the "regular" edition (except for some restrictions such as printing "Student Edition" or printout pages, and more limited direct tech support from WRI. So I hope you realize what a bargain that Student Edition is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Dominic This is really more of a comment on your answer, rather than an answer to your question, but I need to use an image.  There's actually a distinction between the way that `Surd` formats in StandardForm and the way that $x^{1/3}$ formats in traditional form, which can't really be illustrated using $\TeX$ and MathJax.  The following shows `x^(1/3)` and `Surd[x,3]` in both Standard and Tradtional forms.  Also note that there is a specific `CubeRoot` function.

[image]

Note that there's a little extra  hook on the real valued roots to helps distinguish it from the complex valued root. Whether this is truly useful or not is, uh, debateable.

Finally, note that we can use `Surd` for even roots, but they don't accept negative input.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Surd[x, n], {n, 1, 10}]], {x, -1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image]

Comment: One might add that radical notation (for `Power`) can be entered with Ctrl-2 Ctrl-5.  And surd can be entered ESC surd ESC.

Answer (score 12):

As Artes said in the comments, in `Mathematica 9` there is the new function `Surd[x,n]` which gives the real- valued $n^\text{th}$ root of $x$.

In Standardform `Surd[x,n]` formats as $\sqrt[n]{x}$.