# Using Solve to solve the equation $x^{1/3}=-1$

Tags: equation-solving

I am curious why this command returned no answers:

```
Solve[x^(1/3) == -1, x]
```

Gives this output:

```
(* {} *)
```

I was able to get around the problem with this:

```
Solve[Surd[x, 3] == -1, x]
```

Which returns:

```
(* {{x -> -1}} *)
```

But I still wonder why `Solve[x^(1/3) == -1, x]` does not return an answer.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate?: [(3886)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3886/121), [(21151)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21151/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the links, but I don't think they are strictly related to my question. which is "Why doesn't `Solve[x^(1/3) == -1, x]` return any answers?"

Comment: Okay, fair enough. +1 awaiting an answer.

Comment: Not even `Reduce[x^(1/3) == -1]` works, by the way. It just yields `False`

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. I believe that the image of the complex plane under $z\to z^{1/3}$ is $\{r e^{i\theta}: r\geq 0, -\pi/3 < \theta \leq \pi/3\}$, given the location of the branch cut.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMcClure: the branch cut by default is along the negative real axis, and `Solve` looks for solutions among the complex numbers that form the image of $z^{1/3}$. The desired $-1$ is not in that set.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Awesome answer. Thanks for beautiful help. Do you think you can do a quick answer showing the domain, then the range? What would be your favorite command to show this?

Answer (score 17):

I think the negative result of `Solve` and `Reduce` is correct, because the fractional power in question requires choosing a branch of the inverse function to $z\mapsto z^3$. The default in *Mathematica* is to put this cut along the negative real axis. This comes from the fact that the `Arg` function has that same cut, and that fractional powers `1/n` of `x` are obtained from `Abs[x]^(1/n) Exp[I Arg[x]/n]`.

Here is a plot of real and imaginary parts for the image of the standard cube root:

```
plot[f_] := 
 Module[{fn = f /. z -> x + I y}, 
  Show[ContourPlot[Im[fn], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ContourShading -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Red], 
   ContourPlot[Re[fn], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ContourShading -> False, ContourStyle -> Blue, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> Red], FrameLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"}, 
   Background -> Lighter[Orange], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Framed[Grid[{{Style["-", Bold, Blue], 
        "Real part"}, {Style["-", Bold, Gray], "Imaginary part"}}, 
      Alignment -> Left], FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White, 
     RoundingRadius -> 5], ImageSize -> 300]]

plot[z^(1/3)]
```

[image: z root]

The red line is the branch cut. The image does not contain the real number $-1$, as you can see by hovering over the contour lines for the real part.

This code is from another answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44769/245).

Now we can also illustrate how a different branch can be chosen such that it contains the desired result:

```
arg[z_, σ_: - Pi] := 
  Arg[z Exp[-I (σ + Pi)]] + σ + Pi;

plot[Abs[z]^(1/3) Exp[I arg[z, 3 Pi/2]/3]]
```

[image: branch]

The explanation for the `arg` function is in the above link. This image has $-1$ in it, as you can verify by hovering over it. In fact, you get

```
With[{z = -1}, Abs[z]^(1/3) Exp[I arg[z, 3 Pi/2]/3]]

(* ==> -1 *)
```

The above discussion is for inverse functions defined in the *complex plane*, whereas the new function `Surd` is defined only on the *real axis*. `Solve` works with `Surd` because effectively the branch cut is now moved off the real axis, similar to what I showed in the last plot. This is what is meant in the help docs for `Surd` when it says "on the negative axis, `Surd` is different from the principal root returned by `Power`."

Comment: Absolutely tremendous answer.