# Simplifying square root of exponential

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Very simple question: Why doesn't *Mathematica* simplify this square root expression?

```
Refine[Sqrt[Exp[I p]], p > 0] // FullSimplify
```

It should give

```
Exp[I p/2]
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 9):

Just avoid the branch cut:

```
Refine[Sqrt[Exp[I p]], π > p > 0]

(* ==> E^((I p)/2) *)
```

The branch cut of the square-root function doesn't allow *Mathematica* to simplify the expression without the restriction on `p` from above.

See also the related question and answer here: [Using Solve to solve the equation x1/3=−1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104281/245)

Comment: As a side note, the simplification is good for `Pi > p > -Pi`

Comment: ...or more precisely, the range of `Arg[]`, from whom `Power[]` inherits its choice of branch cut.