# Plotting solutions of systems in complex plane

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm interested in plotting solutions of systems of polynomials in the complex plane, in the following way.

Let $f_1,\ldots f_s$ be complex polynomials in variables $x_1,\ldots x_n$. I know how to find the solutions using a code like this

```
eqs = {x^2 + y^3 + 1 == 0, x + y^2 - 1 == 0}
pts = Solve[eqs, {x, y}]
```

But I'm having some trouble to plot the values of $x,y$ n the complex plane. I tried some naive thing like

```
ListPlot[pts]
```

but nothing works. I'm lost, any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Get them using `{x, y} /. %`

Comment: I forgot a little detail in my answer, sorry. It's corrected.

Comment: A math problem: If you have ${x,y}$ as a point and $x$ and $y$ are complex, how does one show them on complex plane?

Comment: $x$ is one point and $y$ is another, their are not considered as coordinates.

Comment: And I just see that data does that, it makes a solution $x$,$y$ into a ordened pair $(x,y)$ which is what I don't want. Basically, if $(x_1,y_1),\ldots, (x_m,y_m)$ are the solutions of the system, I want to plot the points $x_1,y_1,\ldots, x_m, y_m$ in the complex plane.

Comment: [A related thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63028).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
eqs = {x^2 + y^3 + 1 == 0, x + y^2 - 1 == 0};
pts = Solve[eqs, {x, y}];
```

To get the data points and the plot:

```
data = {x, y} /. pts // Flatten;
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ data]
```

Comment: I think it's perfect!

Comment: Do you mind just explain a little (or recommend some reading) what #,&,/ and @ stands for?

Comment: Thanks! `/@` is shorthand for `Map`. It basically maps `{Re[#], Im[#]}` over all elements in `data` one by one. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) page is really good to start!

Answer (score 4):

Starting from version 10.1 you can use `ReIm`:

```
eqs = {x^2 + y^3 + 1 == 0, x + y^2 - 1 == 0};
pts = {x, y} /. Solve[eqs, {x, y}];

ListPlot[ReIm[pts]]
```

[image]

Comment: Or even `ListPlot@ReIm@Values@Solve[eqs, {x, y}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, hi, please let me know what do you think about this question : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206901/plotting-ndsolve-function-in-complex-coordinates . Do you think it’s some how related?

Comment: I have Mathematica 9.