# Plot the critical points of degree $d$ polynomials with zeros randomly chosen in given region

Tags: equation-solving, random, polynomials

I wish to be able to scatter slightly (by at most some fixed $\varepsilon>0$) the zeros of a given complex polynomial $p(z)$ in a random way, and then see the effect on the critical points.

For example, I wish to pick $100$ monic complex polynomials of degree $5$, each of which has one zero within distance $1/100$ of the fifth roots of unity, and then plot the critical points of each of these polynomials.  (The case from the first sentence with $p(z)=z^5-1$, and $\varepsilon=1/100$.)

I am relatively new to using *Mathematica* in this way, so any suggestions or pointers (or of course full solutions!) would be very helpful.

Comment: Before I write an answer that is not correct let me ask something: The five roots of z^5-1 can be constructed with e.g. `Table[Exp[-2/5 Pi I i], {i, 0, 4}]`. If you draw a random complex number that lies within the disk with radius epsilon, you can add them to each root. Then you can reconstruct the polynomial by multiplication (z-root1-rand1)(z-root2-rand2)... You can do this without explicitly specifying the random shifts. The critical points are the zeros of `D[poly,z]`, right? These too can be calculated without values for the random shifts and you get an analytical solution for them.

Comment: If above is what you want, then you have a solution for your critical points, where you only need to insert the random values for the shifts. Plotting them can be done by using `Graphics`, `Point` and `ReIm` and maybe with a nice `ContourPlot` beneath it. Is that what you seek?

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing DumpsterDoofus's routine from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63064), and safening it slightly:

```
With[{γ = 0.12, β = 1.},
     fLor = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}},
                    (γ/(γ + x^2 + y^2))^β, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];

PlotComplexPoints[list_, magnification_, paddingX_, paddingY_, brightness_, vec_] :=
    Module[{dimX, dimY, RePos, ImPos, lor, posf, sparse},
           posf = 1 + Round[magnification (# - Min[#])] &;
           RePos = paddingX + posf[Re[list]]; ImPos = paddingY + posf[Im[list]];
           dimX = paddingX + Max[RePos]; dimY = paddingY + Max[ImPos];
           With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]}, 
                Internal`WithLocalSettings[
                SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}],
                Image[Outer[Times,
                            brightness Abs[InverseFourier[Fourier[
                            SparseArray[Thread[Transpose[{ImPos, RePos}] -> 
                                        ConstantArray[1, Length[list]]], {dimY, dimX}]]
                            Fourier[RotateRight[fLor[#[[All, All, 1]],
                                                     #[[All, All, 2]]] & @
                                    Outer[List, 
                                          Range[-Quotient[dimY, 2],
                                                Quotient[dimY - 1, 2]], 
                                          Range[-Quotient[dimX, 2], 
                                                Quotient[dimX - 1, 2]]],
                                          {Quotient[dimY, 2], Quotient[dimX, 2]}]],
                                    FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]], 
                            Developer`ToPackedArray[N[vec]]], Magnification -> 1],
                SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]]
```

Generate randomly perturbed critical points given the roots:

```
makeRandomCriticalPoints[roots_?VectorQ, h_] := Block[{n = Length[roots], z}, 
    z /. NSolve[D[Product[z - zk,
                          {zk, roots + RandomReal[h, n] Exp[I RandomReal[2 π, n]]}], z],
                z]]
```

Finally:

```
penta = Exp[2 π I Range[0, 4]/5];

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            With[{nPolys = 200, ε = 1/100},
                 PlotComplexPoints[Flatten[Table[makeRandomCriticalPoints[penta, ε],
                            {nPolys}]], 600, 20, 20, 10, {1., 0.3, 0.1}]]]
```

[image: critical points of 200 polynomials with perturbed roots]

A bonus picture:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42];
            With[{nPolys = 200, ε = 1/10},
                 PlotComplexPoints[Flatten[Table[makeRandomCriticalPoints[
                            Riffle[-penta/(1 + GoldenRatio), penta], ε], {nPolys}]],
                                   200, 20, 20, 10, {1., 0.3, 0.1}]]]
```

[image: starburst]

Comment: Omg. Bonus picture doesn't evaluate though: `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in (...) cannot be combined.`

Comment: @Vsevolod, I had inadvertently copied an old version of `makeRandomCriticalPoints[]`. Please try it now.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks very much.  However I have a question.  When I changed the definition of "penta" to do the same thing for $p(z)=z^{50}-1$, by replacing "Range[0, 4]/5" in the definition of "penta" with "Range[0, 49]/50", the behavior is very strange.  Could you try this and see if you can explain the behavior?  Note that when I do the same for $p(z)=z^{30}-1$, the picture is exactly what we expect.  The strange behavior only begins when the number of roots approach $50$.

Comment: I get a picture like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40T8O.png) for `PlotComplexPoints[Flatten[Table[makeRandomCriticalPoints[Exp[2 π I Range[0, 49]/50], 1/100], {100}]], 300, 20, 20, 10, {1., 0.3, 0.1}]`, @Trevor. I see nothing amiss; what were you expecting, exactly?

Comment: @J.M. , Sorry I should have been more specific.  That is exactly the picture I got and the one I was expecting.  It is the second picture, which shows both the zeros and the critical points, where the behavior gets strange when the number of zeros approach 50.  Sorry I don't know how to post pictures as you did (very helpfully), but it looks like some of the critical points scatter towards $1$, and some of the zeros scatter towards $0$.  Please let me know if you see the same.

Comment: That's a pattern I noticed, but I think why it's happening is a math question and not a *Mathematica* question, @Trevor.

Comment: @J.M. If the randomly perturbed zeros were all clustered where they are supposed to be, and the critical points were scattering all over, I would agree with you.  But what appears to me to be the case is that the random perturbations for the zeros close to $1$ are getting messed up.  Moreover, the central structure of the critical points in the second picture does not look like the critical points from the first picture (when the degree approaches $50$), which suggests that something has gone amiss in the Mathematica code regarding the production of the second picture.

Comment: Could it be something in the use of Riffle?  I do not really understand what is happening with dividing by 1+GoldenRatio, but perhaps that is some sort of approximation that starts to break down as the number of zeros increases?  Thanks for the time.

Comment: The "bonus picture" corresponds to the zeroes of a degree $10$ polynomial whose zeroes are arranged in a star shape. You can see the position of the roots themselves by evaluating `With[{penta = Exp[2 π I Range[0, 4]/5]}, ListLinePlot[ReIm[ArrayPad[Riffle[-penta/(1 + GoldenRatio), RotateRight[penta, 2]], {0, 1}, "Periodic"]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]]`, where I shuffled the positions slightly so that everything connects properly.