# Condense code to graph the roots of Littlewood polynomials

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, polynomials, code-review

I am a newbie using Mathematica. I wrote this code to plot the roots of Littlewood polynomials, based on the structure of other programming languages. But I'm sure Mathematica has tools to do it in a more condensed and efficient way. Could you guide me how to do it?

```
poly[exp_, var_] :=
  Times @@@ Tuples[var^Range[0, exp]] //   
  Tuples[{1, -1}, Length@#].# &;

aux[num_] := lista[[num]];

pts = List[];

For[i = 1, i < 15, i++, lista = poly[{i}, {x}];
   For[j = 1, j < Length[lista] + 1, j++,
      pts = Join[pts, ({Re[#1], Im[#1]} &) /@ (x /. 
         NSolve[aux[j] == 0, x])];
   ]
];

graphi = ListPlot[puntos,
         PlotRange -> {{-2.2, 2.2}, {-2.2, 2.2}},
         AspectRatio -> Automatic,
         PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.0000001],
            Opacity[0.05],
            Yellow
         },
         Axes -> False,
         Background -> Black,
         ImageSize -> 1000,
         GridLines -> {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}}
];

Export["/Animaciones/Littlewood/14.png", graphi];
```

Use `aux[num_]:=lista[[num]];` because `({Re[#1], Im[#1]} &) /@ (x /.NSolve[lista[[j]] == 0, x])` gave me an error, and `pts=List[];` to have an empty list. As seen in the first `For`, this code generates the roots of the Littlewood polynomials with $n = 14$.

Also, is it normal for Mathematica on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) to use only one thread at a time in its calculations? I think a lot of processing power is wasted.

Comment: You can use something like `ReIm@Values@NSolve[ lista[[j]] == 0, x]` instead as no need for separate `Re` and`Im`, and `ReIm` is listable. You should consider using a Table, or `Reap+Sow+Flatten` to achieve what's going on in the loops.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73312/2090

Answer (score 8):

The roots can be represented directly and exactly with [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects; there is no need to invoke `Solve` or `NSolve` explicitly. For a given tuple `t` we can list them with

```
F[t_] := Array[Root[#^Range[0, 11].t &, #] &, 11]
```

or, more generally for arbitrary polynomial degree,

```
F[t_] := With[{n = Length[t] - 1},
  Array[Root[#^Range[0, n].t &, #] &, n]]
```

Example:

```
F[{1, 1, -1}]
(*    {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}    *)

F[{-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1}]
(*    {-1.52929, -1.13608, -1., -0.461159 - 0.792192 I, -0.461159 + 0.792192 I,
       0.300042 - 1.08437 I, 0.300042 + 1.08437 I, 0.646434 - 0.281355 I,
       0.646434 + 0.281355 I, 0.847365 - 0.608848 I, 0.847365 + 0.608848 I}    *)
```

Plot them with [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html):

```
ComplexListPlot[F /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 12]]
```

[image]

Alternatively (faster), by taking the product of all of these polynomials and setting this product to zero, we can find all solutions in one go:

```
With[{n = 11},
  ComplexListPlot[x /. Solve[Times @@ (1 + Tuples[{-1, 1}, n].x^Range[n]) == 0, x]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I thought I'd seen this before!

In-fact you can do all of this *and* plot it in under 128 characters:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny],Point@Flatten[((ReIm[z]/.#)&/@NSolve[z^Range[0,11].#==0,z])&/@Tuples[{-1,1},12],1]}]
```

[image]

The credit goes to Yuncong Ma's Honorable Mention Entry from the [2012 one-liner competition](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=282&v=691). The terse syntax is explained in the video above, but happy to help break it down further if needed.

With regards to efficiency, I suspect there's improvements to be made - but the bulk of this is spent inside `NSolve` so perhaps unlikely..

Comment: +1 With Manipulate: `Manipulate[Graphics[{PointSize[Which[n < 4, Large, n < 6, Medium, n < 9, Small, True, Tiny]], Point@Flatten[((ReIm[z] /. #) &  /@ 
 NSolve[z^Range[0, n].# == 0, z]) & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, n + 1], 1]}], {{n, 11}, Range[11]}]`

Answer (score 3):

If I use the [safened version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169215) of [DumpsterDoofus's visualization routine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63064) with the last formulation in Roman's answer, I get this:

```
With[{n = 11}, 
     PlotComplexPoints[x /. NSolve[Times @@ (1 + Tuples[{-1, 1}, n].x^Range[n]), x],
                       600, 20, 20, 10, {0.1, 0.3, 1.}]]
```

[image: Littlewood polynomial roots]

Comment: Wow that’s a beautiful representation!