# Ghost trails with Animate?

Tags: graphics, animation

What are some approaches to integrate [Ghost trails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/creating-ghost-trail-effects) methods with Animate, which otherwise seem more suited for exporting individual frames?

For example, given this [rootPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/the-plot-of-roots-of-polynomials/25127#25127) function, how can trails be added and displayed as a dynamic alterative to `RootLocusPlot`?

```
Animate[rootPlot[(Range[0, 20, 3] // Map[x^# &] // Apply[Plus]) + 
    k x^3, x] // Show[{Graphics@{Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, #},
    PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True] &,
 {k, -50, 50, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating ghost trail effects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/creating-ghost-trail-effects)

Comment: @chuy, I linked to that question already (first line), but here the focus is on `Animate`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It really helps others reading your code if you split things up and name parts of the code. Let's start with the polynomial.

```
polynomial[k_] := Total[x^Range[0, 20, 3]] + k x^3;
```

and the function that finds the roots, and the function that visualizes them

```
roots[poly_, x_] := roots[poly, x] = Through@*{Re, Im} /@ (x /. NSolve[poly, x])
frame[k_, opacity_] := ListPlot[
  roots[polynomial[k], x],
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[opacity]
  ]
```

And the background can also have its own name so that it is clearly distinguishable in the code.

```
background = Graphics[{
    Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]
    },
   PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
   Axes -> True
   ];
```

Now, a ghost trail is nothing but a plot that includes the current frame and the last `lag` number of frames, with each frame faded by age.

```
visualize[k_, lag_, {min_, max_}] := 
 visualize[k, lag, {min, max}] = Module[{mink, frames},
   mink = Max[min, k - lag];
   frames = frame[#, (# - mink)/(k - mink)] & /@ Range[mink, k];
   Show[background, Sequence @@ frames]
   ]
```

And so finally:

```
Animate[
 visualize[k, 10, {-50,50}],
 {k, -50, 50}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: And it helps copying the code if it is not riffled with text :P

Comment: @Kuba I know, but I think my reasons for sacrificing copyability are sound.

Comment: Maybe text as comment in code block is a good idea? I don't know, I'm just thinking about general approach because often when I have to do multiple copy+paste I just skip that :P

Comment: @Kuba But then, you wouldn't have the joy of writing code to extract the code. :) `code=StringJoin[Cases[First[Cases[Import["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75936/ghost-trails-with-animate","XMLObject"], XMLElement["td", {_, _, "class" -> "answercell"}, ___],Infinity]],XMLElement["pre", {}, {XMLElement["code", _, {code_}]}] :> code, Infinity]]`

Comment: Sadly, the Import code I just wrote doesn't seem to survive a copy from the comment box.  Hopefully, you get the idea.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I do, very nice! Try ``StringJoin[
    Cases[First[
      Cases[Import[
        "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75941/5478", 
        "XMLObject"], 
       XMLElement["td", {_, _, "class" -> "answercell"}, ___], 
       Infinity]], 
     XMLElement["pre", {}, {XMLElement["code", _, {code_}]}] :> code, 
     Infinity]] // 
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
     FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[#, True]] & // 
  Cell[#[[1]], "Input"] & // CellPrint``

Comment: @Kuba Neat! I never noticed a function that actually declares itself as undocumented in its name before.  I'm curious - how did you avoid the problem that I had with the misbehaving invisible characters after copy/paste?  It looks like you used 4 space indentation; maybe that's it? My code was inline.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Maybe it is OS specific. Your code worked as it is for me. [UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/5478)

Comment: @Kuba. I don't think interspersing text with code adds any significant difficulty to copying the code.

Comment: Pickett, this is nice, thanks.