# obtaining real roots of negative numbers in a long expression

Tags: numerics, replacement

I have a complicated symbolic expression which contains many terms like $(a/(a-2))^{1/m}$, where $a/(a-2)$ could be positive or negative after replacement.

I only need the real root after replacement, but `Power[]` function in *Mathematica* most of the time gives me a complex number instead. I found something that almost suits my need [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8) (the `realPower` function by Peter Breitfeld), but I have a hard time get it working in the way I want.

For example:

```
((a/(-2 + a))^(1/3) /. {x_^y_ :> realPower[x, y]}) /. {a -> 0.5}
```

still gives me a complex number. (it seems that `realPower` only work with numerical values)  What should I do to get only the real root after replacement?

Comment: If you read another answers to the question you linked to in your post you wouldn't have asked this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Surd.html) is your friend:

```
Surd[a/(-2 + a), 3] /. a -> 0.5
```

> -0.693361

It can be entered in formatted form as <kbd>Esc</kbd> surd <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image]

`Surd` was introduced in *Mathematica* 9. In previous versions you can use

```
((a/(-2 + a))^(1/3) /. {x_^y_ :> Sign[x] Abs[x]^y}) /. {a -> 0.5}
```

> -0.693361