# Is this an error/bug with Plot Command?

Tags: plotting

I've tried doing:

```
Plot[x^(2/3), {x, -10, 10}]
```

and I get

[image]

Which is wrong, since the cubic root can receive negative numbers. Also when I plot something supposedly equivalent

```
Plot[(x^2)^(1/3), {x, -10, 10}]
```

I get

[image]

I would understand this kind of behaviour by the Plot command if instead of (1/3) we had (1/even number). But with (1/odd number) the domain of the function should be all the real numbers. 
Or am I wrong??

Comment: try `N@(-1)^(2/3)` ...

Comment: @belisarius (-1)^(1/3) // N gives 0.5 + 0.866025 I which is wrong...

-1*-1*-1= -1

Comment: @belisarius (0.5000000000000001` + 0.8660254037844386` I)^3 gives 
-1. + 3.88578*10^-16 I

Comment: Look at `Series[a^x, {x, 0, 5}]` and replace `a` by `-1`

Comment: @belisarius, I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you mean. You're saying that Plot uses series approximations instead of the true functions?

Comment: Or you're saying that Mathematica doesn't consider x^(1/3) to be the inverse of x^3 ?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: In complex numbers, $x^{1/3}$ *is* indeed not the inverse of $x^3$. For example, $((-1)^3)^{1/3}\ne -1$. Actually, for even exponents, the same is already true in the real numbers, where $((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1 \ne -1$. Only for positive $x$ the two functions are inverse to each other.

Comment: Please do not use the `bugs` tag when posting new questions.  This tag is a bit special as it gets added only later when several people agree that the problem is really a bug.  It's to avoid accidentally tagging non-bugs as bugs.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Copy that. ;)

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3886/57) or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33009/obtaining-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-in-a-long-expression). Related: [plotting-complex-quantity-functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/plotting-complex-quantity-functions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the root of this behaviour (no pun intended) as follows:

```
(-1)^(2/3)//ComplexExpand
(*
==> -1/2 + (I/2)*Sqrt[3]
*)
```

You can also check that this solution is correct, by doing

```
%^(3/2)
(*
==> -1
*)
```

So what is happening? Strictly speaking, a non-integer power does not have a single value, but many values. For example, there are two values of $1^{1/2}$, namely $+1$ and $-1$, because $1^2=(-1)^2=1$. Therefore when calculating the power, you have to choose one.

When the base is real and positive, the convention is to take the root that also is real and positive. However, what to take when the base is negative?

Your expectation is that for odd denominator of the exponent, you would get the root that is real and negative. When considering the function as a purely real one, this makes sense, because after all, in the real numbers there exists no other solution (and for other denominators, there's generally no solution at all).

However Mathematica interprets this as complex exponentiation, as shown above. And for complex exponentiation, it makes more sense to use the same rule as for other exponents (where you don't have a real solution), and this is done using a so-called branch cut.

To understand what this means, consider that you can write every complex number in polar form as $z=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ with $r\ge 0$ and $\phi$ in some half-open interval of length $2\pi$ (because adding $2\pi$ to $\phi$ gives the same number $z$ again). The selection of the interval is exactly what determines the so-called branch cut (that is, in the end the branch cut determines which of the infinitely many possible values of $\phi$ is chosen for a given $z$).

Mathematica uses the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$, which has the nice property that you get the intuitive result $(-1)^{1/2}=\mathrm i$ and also plays well with complex conjugation.

Now in polar form, simple arithmetics gives you $z^\alpha = r^\alpha \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi\alpha}$. Nor consider the famous formula $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi}=-1$, and you immediately get $(-1)^{2/3} = \mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi/3}=-\frac{1}{2}+\mathrm i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$, which is indeed the result Mathematica gives you, as shown above.

So why does `Plot` show nothing in the negative area? Well, simply because only real numbers are plotted.

And finally, why does `(x^2)^(1/3)` give the result you desired? Well, let's look again at the case $-1$: $(-1)^2=1$, and $1^{1/3}=1$. You can verify both results in the polar representation with the chosen branch cut.

Generally, the rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ *only* holds if either $a>0$ or $b$ and $c$ are integers. Neither is the case in your code for $x<0$.

The following gives you the real solution if it exists (probably there are simpler ways, but I don't know them):

```
realpower[x_, y_Rational] :=
  If[x>=0 || Denominator[y]==1, x^y,
     Module[{tmp, sol},
            sol=Solve[tmp^Denominator[y] == x^Numerator[y], tmp, Reals];
            If[sol=={},Undefined,tmp/.First@sol]]]
```

Comment: So, by default it represents the number in polar form. Is there a way to make plot use real numbers usual representation only? Because the left side is still missing...

Comment: Also, thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: Actually, it is not the *representation*, but the *definition* of the complex power. It's just easiest described in the polar representation (most probably, internally the formula $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$ is used, together with an appropriate branch cut for $\ln x$). However see my edit for a function that does what you want (but probably has a lot of room for improvement).

Comment: Ok. Many thanks ;)

Comment: Instead of `realpower`, you should look into `Surd` and `CubeRoot`.

Comment: @ChipHurst: Both seem not to be available at Mathematica 8; however I've found them in the web documentation. `CubeRoot` clearly wouldn't be a replacement for `realpower`, covering only the very special case $x^{1/3}$. `Surd` (which IMHO is a contender for the most unintuitively named Mathematica function) gives the more general case $x^{1/n}$; while it would certainly be a better building block for `realpower`, it's however not a full replacement because it doesn't handle e.g. $x^{2/3}$ (which is the case from the question).

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, although `(-3)^3` is -27 the reverse is not so, because -3 is just one amongst other possible answer, so the answer is kept in the complex form.  E.g.

[image]

These are the possible answers:-

[image]