# Applying N to the roots found by Solve gives complex numbers when the roots are real

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have a function which is

```
f(x) = x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1.
```

When I solve for x to find the zeros

```
Solve[x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1 == 0, x]
N[%]
```

it gives the answers

> ```
> {{x -> 2.36147 - 1.11022*10^-16 I}, {x -> -2.52892 + 0. I}, {x -> 0.167449 + 0. I}}
> ```

and I want to plot these points on the graph but I don't get accurate results. please help!

Comment: First, before asking you should look for similar answers, in fact this was answered many times,  see e.g. [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, −8−−−√3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888)

Comment: Use `Chop`. It will cut off very small numbers. In yur case you'll be able to ged rid of the imaginary part.

Comment: Just use `NSolve` instead of `Solve`

Answer (score 4):

My first observation is that

> ```
> {{x -> 2.36147 - 1.11022*10^-16 I}, {x -> -2.52892 + 0. I}, {x -> 0.167449 + 0. I}}
> ```

is not a set of solutions for

```
 x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1 == 0
```

This can be seen by plotting the polynomial

```
Plot[x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1, {x, -1., 6.}]
```

[image: plot]

However, the problem of imaginary fuzz in the roots remains.

```
Solve[x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1 == 0, x] // N
```

> ```
> {
>   {x -> -0.525428 - 4.44089*10^-16 I}, 
>   {x -> 0.369102 + 6.66134*10^-16 I}, 
>   {x -> 5.15633 - 1.4803*10^-16 I}
> }
> ```

`Solve` takes a token, `Reals`, which instructs it constrain solutions to be over the real numbers. This will eliminate numeric imaginary fuzz.

```
Solve[x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1 == 0, x, Reals] // N
```

> ```
> {{x -> -0.525428}, {x -> 0.369102}, {x -> 5.15633}}
> ```

Why is there a difference? In the first case, `Solve` returns a complex expression involving cube roots. Then, when `N` is applied, the machine numerics used for taking the cube root expressions produce a small error in the imaginary part. In the second `Solve` avoids the cube roots and returns `Root` objects.

The imaginary free result can also be achieved with

```
 Solve[x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 1 == 0, x, Cubics -> False] // N
```