# Equality of Reciprocal with Negative Exponent

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want MMA to tell me if two, rather large, expressions are equal.  My minimum working example follows.  I want MMA to tell me that the following is true:$$x^n = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-n}$$
I have tried

```
x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n)
```

and

```
FullSimplify[x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n)]
```

Neither indicates that the expressions are equal. In fact:

```
PossibleZeroQ[x^n - (x^(-1))^(-n)]
```

returns `False`.  Is there any way to get MMA to tell me that the equality holds? Or maybe a better approach/paradigm?

Comment: It's not generally true, but it is for integers.  Try `FullSimplify[x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n), n \[Element] Integers]`. -- Also for positive bases: `FullSimplify[x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n), x > 0]`

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the pitfalls new users face, especially if they have analysis (calculus) of only real functions of real variables, is that *Mathematica* assumes by default that variables are complex and functions are the complex functions.  Power functions in particular can seem strange; even those who know it is complex sometimes forget.  The cube root is a simple example:

```
(-1)^(1/3)
(*  (-1)^(1/3)         -- not -1  *)

N[(-1)^(1/3)]
(*  0.5 + 0.866025 I   -- it's a complex 3rd root of -1 *)
```

We can see that the OP's proposed identity does not hold generally:

```
Block[{x = -1, n = 1/3},
 N@ {x^n, (x^(-1))^(-n)}
 ]
(*  {0.5 + 0.866025 I, 0.5 - 0.866025 I}   -- different imaginary parts  *)
```

There are two cases where it does hold:

```
FullSimplify[x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n), n ∈ Integers]
FullSimplify[x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n), x > 0]
(*
  True
  True
*)
```

One can find other cases, too:

```
Block[{x = I, n = 1/3},
 x^n == (x^(-1))^(-n)]
(*  True  *)
```

Related:

- [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)
- [Applying N to the roots found by Solve gives complex numbers when the roots are real](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60278/applying-n-to-the-roots-found-by-solve-gives-complex-numbers-when-the-roots-are/60330#60330)
- [Why is (-1.)^2. a complex number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71675/why-is-1-2-a-complex-number/72157#72157)