# Why mathematica is not default set to give real solution, instead of complex one?

Tags: equation-solving

**N[(-8)^(1/3)]** gives **1. + 1.73205 i**.

Since $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ has **three possible solutions**, **one real and other two are complex**.

So, why do not mathematica provides all the three solutions, and if it has to definitely choose only one solution then why not the REAL one ? Just curious !

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8 So use CubeRoot[-8] or Surd[-8, 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bob Hanlon said, you can use `CubeRoot` to get one root.

According to you question (the tree possible solutions) you can also simply use this:

```
Solve[x^3 == 8] // N
```