# Expand the plotting range

Tags: plotting

When use the following command to plot a graph

```
Plot[x^(1/3), {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: figure]

Mathematica does not show the range `[0, 1]`. It does not show the range `[-1, 0]`. While for function `1/x` it does.

```
Plot[1/x, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: figure]

How can I make Mathematica show the range specified for `x^(1/3)` ?

Comment: It doesn't plot imaginary numbers (such as the root of a negative number) because the plot coordinate system is over the real cartesian 2D space. You can use `Re` to obtain the real component and plot that.

Comment: There's also `CubeRoot` and `Surd` for real-valued functions.

Comment: The problem is not with `Plot` but with the cube root itself. See [Finding real roots of negative numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3886/484).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematics one.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[{Re[x^(1/3)], Im[x^(1/3)]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

or plotting the modulus:

```
Plot[Abs[x^(1/3)], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: With PlotRange->Full, Mathematica still only show the positive range. (I use Mathematica 9.)