# Plot3D of $z^{1/3}$

Tags: plotting

When I do `Plot3D[z^(1/3), {z, -10, 10}]` in *Mathematica*, it just outputs the command back to me. There is no plot.

Oddly, Wolfram Alpha displays a plot just fine.

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D[z^%281%2F3%29%2C++[z%2C+-10%2C+10]]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D[z%5E%281%2F3%29%2C%20%20[z%2C%20-10%2C%2010]])

Is there something different that I have to do in *Mathematica*?

Comment: 1) A `Plot3D` needs two dimensions, try `Plot`. 2) You're going to end up with complex numbers so you'll probably need to specify `Re[z^(1/3)]` or `Im[z^(1/3)]`, or you'll wind up with inexplicably empty regions. To get the plots you're seeing in Alpha do `Plot3D[Re[z^(1/3),{z,-10,10},{x,-10,10}]` or `Plot3D[Im[z^(1/3),{z,-10,10},{x,-10,10}]`

Comment: Try `Plot3D[Re@(z^(1/3)), {z, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`
`Plot3D[Im@(z^(1/3)), {z, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`

Comment: In addition to using `Plot` instead of `Plot3D`, you will probably want to use `CubeRoot[z]` instead of `z^(1/3)`. The former uses the surd form (suitable for getting real values on negative input) whereas the latter uses the principal root.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Well, not if $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: @BrettChampion I think I will ignore you and just discuss this with my imaginary friend..

Comment: [A related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886)