# Plotting roots of a predefined complex polynomial

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following :

```
 w[n_] := E^((2*I*\[Pi])/n)
 Phi[n_, k_, x_] := (1/n)*Sum[(w[n]^(-j*k)*E^(x*w[n]^j)), {j, 0, n - 1}]
 NEuler[n_, x_] := (1/Phi[n, 0, x])
 NEulerPoly[n_, x_, z_] := (E^(x*(z - 1/n)))/Phi[n, 0, x/n]
 NEPoly[n_, z_, r_, M_] := Expand[FullSimplify[Coefficient[r!Normal[Series[NEulerPoly[n, x, z], {x, 0, M}]], x,  r]]]
```

The polynomials in z are indexed by r and form a sequence $\{z\}_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$.  I would like to look at the roots of these complex polynomials by extracting the real and imaginary parts and plotting them as an ordered pair, or by some other method.  HOwever, I have no idea how to do this.  I don't know mathematica very good and am trying to learn the commands and functions that can handle this type of procedure.

Comment: `Plot[ReIm@(your function),(your domain)]`?

Comment: That seems to plot the actual polynomial, not the complex roots of the polynomial...

Comment: You can find appropriate ideas here: [Finding real roots of negative numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888)

Comment: When I try to evaluate NEPoly, I get all zeroes: `NEPoly[n, z, r, #] & /@ Range[20]`

Comment: I used a term $M$...it must be greater than or equal to r. So it you try and print when $r=5$, $M\ge 5$

Comment: Here's a start: `ListPlot[{Re[z], Im[z]} /. 
   Table[Solve[0 == NEPoly[2, z, r, 20], z], {r, 1, 10}] // N]`.

Comment: If the answers in the linked thread were not useful, please edit your question to mention why the solutions there could not be adapted to your situation.

Comment: @march, is there any way to just get a single value for r instead of a list plot for all r up to a particular value?

Comment: Just replace the `Table[]`: `Solve[0 == NEPoly[2, z, 10, 20], z]`, for instance.