# how to plot complex numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I have a very simple equation that I want to plot in Mathematica without Wolfram Alpha and I am having some trouble. This is the equation [ z^7 = 1 - i ] and I have used eq3 = Solve[{z^7 == 1 - i}, {z}] and found the answers but I want to plot them now but Plot function doesn't plot it. I tried CounterPlot and DensityPlot and neither of these functions is plotting it. please help!

I would really appreciate a link to the functions that plot this. I searched but I can't find anything

Comment: You have an answer here [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888)

Comment: @Red, please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged.