# Finding the roots of a polynomial that meet specified conditions

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

> Find the largest real root and the largest real part of a root of the
>   polynomial below. Clearly indicate which is which.
>
> $$f(x) = 5 -\sum_{k=1}^{100}k^2 x^k$$
>
> To get all roots, solve for $f(x) = 0$.

```
f[x_] := 5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}]
NSolve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

How can I select:

1. The largest real root?
2. The largest real part of a root?

My thinking is something along the lines of

```
Select[roots, {Element[roots, Reals]}]
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would you adjust this to find the largest real root?

Comment: `sols = x /. Solve[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}] == 0, x]; Max[N@Re[sols]]` and `rsols = x /. Solve[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}] == 0, x, Reals]; Max[N@Re[rsols]] `.  For a wider perspecitve see e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888).

Comment: If an approximate root is acceptable, could do `In[24]:= Max[Cases[x /. NSolve[f[x] == 0, x], _Real]]

Out[24]= 0.478778284362` and `In[26]:= Max[Re[x /. NSolve[f[x] == 0, x]]]

Out[26]= 0.959209369278`.

Answer (score 4):

`Solve` conveniently gives the complete list in terms of `Root` objects, ordered by their real parts, from least to most, with all complex roots following the real ones. So,

```
First[-x /. Solve[f[-x] == 0, x]] // N
(* 0.478778 *)
```

gets you the largest real root. It uses `-x` to reverse the ordering to put the largest root first. Then,

```
Re[Last[x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]] // N
(* 0.959209 *)
```

yields the real part of the complex root with the largest real part. No reversal for this case.

Leave out `// N` for exact algebraic results (long `Root` expressions).

Comment: Without reversal, `x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[-1]] // N` For the largest real part of a root, `Root[f[x], 100] // N // Re`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to proceed is to use `CountRoots[]` + `RootIntervals[]` for finding the real roots:

```
CountRoots[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}], {x, -∞, ∞}]
   2
```

which tells us that there are two real roots, and

```
RootIntervals[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}]]
   {{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1}, {1}}}
```

which tells us that the largest real root is within $(0,1)$; thus:

```
x /. First[NSolve[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}] == 0 && 0 < x < 1,
                  x, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
   0.4787782843622795018143755
```

---

For the case of getting the root with the largest real part, we can again use `RootIntervals[]` to find isolating intervals, and then pick out the most extreme bounds:

```
recs = First[RootIntervals[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}], Complexes]];

cand = MaximalBy[Select[recs, Im[Last[#]] > 0 &], Re @* Last]
   {{7/8, 1 + I/8}, {15/16 + I/8, 1 + I/4}, {3/4 + I/2, 1 + I}}
```

which leaves us with three candidates, instead of a hundred. From there:

```
(x /. First[NSolve[5 - Sum[k^2 x^k, {k, 1, 100}] == 0 &&
                   #[[1, 1]] < Re[x] < #[[2, 1]] &&
                   #[[1, 2]] < Im[x] < #[[2, 2]], x, 
                   WorkingPrecision -> 25]]) & /@ ReIm[cand]
   {0.9592093692777315093832973 + 0.0800374424094000451900130 I, 
    0.9423637156463657775951992 + 0.1412604810949637296158256 I, 
    0.7745164783087352268927909 + 0.5155444841877413797413391 I}
```

and it is clear that the first root returned has the largest real part.