# How to make Mathematica recognize $(-1)^{1/3}$ as $-1$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am doing some calculations that end up popping out a lot of $-1$s to various fractional powers, and Mathematica doesn't seem to want to set them to $-1$. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: See if you agree with the output of `ComplexExpand[(-1)^(1/3), TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`.

Comment: If you know you're only interested in the real roots when you're taking roots, you might be interested in using `Surd` instead of fractional powers.

Comment: These solutions both seemed to have work. On a more general note, I have a variable $L$ that I am using.  I have other terms that are written in terms of $L$.  At some point in my output, Mathematica writes "$\sqrt{L^2} \sqrt{L}$." How can I force them to combine?

Comment: `Simplify` can be given an optional second argument defining things to assume during the simplification process, thus `Simplify[Sqrt[L^2]Sqrt[L],L>=0]` returns `L^(3/2)`

Comment: @Bill so if I make that assumption earlier in my code will it assume that every time, or will I need to write that every time L appears?

Comment: @swygerts If you assign `$Assumptions = {L >= 0}` then it is assumed automatically

Comment: Only some functions in Mathematica check the assumptions only under some conditions. `Simplify` is one of those. As you might have seen, if you type in some expression there is a default very lightweight quick simplification done to that, like 3+5 being replaced by 8, but that does not invoke all the power of `Simplify` or make use of all the power of `Assumptions`. That means Mathematica works much more quickly if you choose when and where you want to have it spend time doing `Simplify` and using `Assumptions`

Comment: There was a special function `CubeRoot` added in V9 to handle this kind of problem. It accepts only real-valued arguments and returns only the real valued root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question: 
`(-1)^(1/3)` is not equal to `-1`
`(-1)^n` is only equal to `-1` for odd, integer values of n.

Second Question:
Try `Assuming[L \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify[Sqrt[L^2] Sqrt[L]]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
rule = x_^(1/3) -> CubeRoot[x];

(-1)^(1/3) /. rule
(*-1*)
```