# Why PlotLegends does not work in Plot3D?

Tags: complex, polynomials, legending

I'm trying to plot a complex polynomial function in 3D using the Plot3D function. The PlotLegends seems not working as it does not show the legends.

A similar issue I've while plotting a 2D plot using the plot function. The PlotLegends shows the legend along the X-axis but not the other.

```
enter code here
y=Range[0.1,10];

x=(-p11*(1/xi+I k)-p44*(1/xi+I k)*(I k-1/xi)+p66*(1/xi^2+k^2)+y*(q22*(1/xi+I 
k)-q33*(1/xi+I k)(1/xi-I k)-q44*(1/xi^2+k^2)))/(p22+p33*(I k-1/xi)-p55* 
(1/xi^2+k^2));
Table[Re[x],{xi,0.1,10,0.5},{k,10,100,5}]//TableForm;
Plot3D[Re[x],{xi,0.1,10},{k,10,100}, BoundaryStyle- 
>Directive[Red,Thick],PlotLegends->{"\[Xi]","k"},AxesLabel->{\ 
[Xi],k,Subscript[\[CapitalOmega],r]},Mesh->{{0}},BoxRatios->{1,1,1}]

enter code here
xi=0.5;
Plot[Im[y],{k,0,100},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Red,Thick},AxesLabel-> 
{"k","Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], i]"},Frame->True,FrameStyle- 
>Thick,PlotLegends->{"k","Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], i]"},AspectRatio->0.5]
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888).

Comment: Make sure that any code you post can be copied back into a notebook intact. Use code blocks for code. Always show a *minimal* example. http://sscce.org/