# Ordinary differential equation in the real domain

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, complex

If I have the following equation

```
(y - 1) ^5 == 32
```

I can select the real solution with

```
Solve[(y - 1) ^5 == 32, x, Reals]
```

Now, I have the following differential equation

```
y'[x] == Cos[x] / (y[x] - 1) ^4
```

and the implicit solution should be

```
(y[x] - 1) ^5 == 5 Sin[x] + 5 C[1])
```

`DSolve` gives the five complex solutions in the form

```
y[x] -> Root[...]
```

How can I ask only for the solution?

```
y[x] -> 1 + (5 Sin[x] + 5 C[1]) ^ (1/5)
```

Comment: A first order ode (satisfying the Lipschitz condition) may have only one solution to the Cauchy problem. Whenever writing `(5 Sin[x] + 5 C[1]) ^ (1/5)`  the system doesn't know which one of 5 solutions is appropriate and for certain initial conditions there are no solutions.

Comment: @Artes: for what I know, Mathematica gives a well defined meaning to `x^(1/5)`: it is the root with the greater real part, and between these, the one with greater imaginary part.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Examine e.g. this post [Finding real roots of negative numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8/3888#3888).  I guess that your question cannot be answered reasonably in this form unless you make precise statements. `Mathematica` provides 5 roots and one of them could be an appropriate solution to the Cauchy problem.  This is non-trivial problem, since in general  there are no exact radicals to fifth order polynomials.

Comment: @Artes: it remains the fact that something that can easily be done by hand (for `C[1]>=1` the solution that I wrote exists and is a real function, while the others four are always complex, assuming `x` and `C[1]` real), cannot be automated by Mathematica.

Comment: I think that formulating the problem this way: find the uniqe (explicit) solution to this problem `DSolve[y'[x] == Cos[x]/(y[x] - 1)^4 && y[0] == 0, y[x], x]` is well defined and you could expect a correct solution. You might also reformulate the problem to make `(5 Sin[x] + 5 C[1]) ^ (1/5)`  a solution. This needs finding appropriate restriction for `C[1]`.