# Obtain real roots

Tags: algebra

I'm evaluating polynomials that are solvables by radicals in their algebraic solutions but it allways return complex values. Apparently the main issue is with the radicals e.g.

N[(-1)^(1/3)]

returns 0.5 + 0.866025i

instead of -1 (which is the real one of the three roots)

To solve by radicals I need that whenever I ask for a root it assume the real one (possitive if possible),

as in Sqrt[4]

it returns 2 and not -2

Comment: You could e.g. use `Solve`and specify `Reals` as domain:  `Solve[x^3 == -1, x, Reals]`

Comment: Instead of `(-1)^(1/3)` use `Surd[-1, 3]` to get the real root.

Comment: This question has been asked [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)