# Slopefield curves for various points

Tags: plotting

I want to find the Slopefield curve for the ODE

\begin{equation}
y'=y^{2/3}
\end{equation}

at the points given under.

```
In[72]:= ClearAll
   
     
In[77]:= initvalues1 = {{0, 0}, {-1, 3}, {3, 3}}

Out[77]= {{0, 0}, {-1, 3}, {3, 3}}

In[78]:= SlopeField[Evaluate[y' == 2 y^(2/3)], {y, -6., 6.}, {x, -6., 6.}, initvalues1]

Out[78]= SlopeField[
 1/27 (6 C[1]^2 + 24 C[1] #1 + 24 #1^2) & == 2 y^(2/3), {y, -6., 6.}, {x, -6.,
   6.}, {{0, 0}, {-1, 3}, {3, 3}}]
```

But I get no plot at all.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: The reason is that "SlopeField" is no MMA command.

Comment: What is MMA? ..

Comment: Mathematica   program

Comment: For [reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SlopeField.html).

Comment: As to "why?", compare output of `Table[y^(2/3), {y, -1., 1., 0.5}]` with that of `Table[CubeRoot[y^2], {y, -1., 1., 0.5}]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because: 1. As pointed out by @Daniel , definition of `SlopeField` is missing. 2. Even if the definition is added, this is probably a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3886/1871

Comment: BTW, `ClearAll` won't do what you're imagining, please read the document carefully. One correct wayto "clear all" is ``Clear@"`*"``.

Comment: Thanks for that xcdz!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use `VectorPlot` and `CubeRoot` for `y^(1/3)`.

```
initvalues1 = {{0, 0}, {-1, 3}, {3, 3}};
VectorPlot[{1, 2 CubeRoot[y^2]}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 VectorPoints -> initvalues1, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[initvalues1]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
StreamPlot[{1, 2 CubeRoot[y^2]}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 VectorPoints -> initvalues1, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[initvalues1]}]
```

[image]

- emphasize some lines

```
initvalues1 = {{0, 0}, {-1,3},{3,3}};
 colors = {Red, Green, Yellow};
 StreamPlot[{1, 2 CubeRoot[y^2]}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 VectorPoints -> initvalues1, 
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[initvalues1]}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{Sequence @@ Thread[{initvalues1, colors}], 
    Automatic}}, StreamColorFunction -> None]
```

[image]