# How to choose between the principal root (complex) and the real root when calculating a definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following integral gives a complex answer in Wolfram Cloud (basic account):

```
N[Integrate[(2+x)^(1/5)*(1+x^2)^(1/4),{x,-3,-0}]]
```

3.37527+0.809411i

However, Wolfram Alpha let me choose between using the real root or the principal root.  The answer for the integral using the real root is 0.884167

[image]

I have tried with Assumptions->x>-2, Assumptions->x^2+1>0 but the answer remains complex.  How can I obtain the real-valued solution for the integral in Wolfram Language?

Thanks.

Comment: In principle integration has nothing to add with respect to an old question [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r=Integrate[Surd[(2+x),5]*(1+x^2)^(1/4),{x,-3,0}]
N[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Chop[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]