# Why is the result of solving this inequality incomplete?Is it a BUG in the software?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Solve this inequality

```
In[41]:= Reduce[x^2 > x^(1/3), x, Reals]

Out[41]= x > 1
```

Missing a solution as

```
x<0
```

There was also an error in drawing images of two functions within the same coordinate system

```
Plot[{x^2, x^(1/3)}, {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotHighlighting -> "XSlice"]
```

[image]

The correct image is

[image]

In[45]:= FunctionDomain[x^(1/3), x]

Out[45]= x >= 0

The Domain of a function of this function is also wrong

Comment: if $x<0$ then $x^{1/3}$ is not real?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding real roots of negative numbers (for example, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mathematica, `x^(1/3)===Power[x,1/3]` is a complex function which is difference from the real cube root of `x`.

we should use

```
Reduce[x^2 > CubeRoot[x], x, Reals]
```

> `x < 0 || x > 1`.

or

```
Reduce[x^2 > Root[#^3 - x &, 1], x, Reals]
```

> `x < 0 || x > 1`.

```
Plot[{x^2, Root[#^3 - x &, 1]}, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]