# How to correctly represent any Power function and How to draw the image of Power function correctly?

Tags: complex

[Why is the result of solving this inequality incomplete?Is it a BUG in the software?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287761/why-is-the-result-of-solving-this-inequality-incompleteis-it-a-bug-in-the-softw)

According to cvgmt's answer to the previous question, I review the function images of Power function again, and some of them are also wrong. In the software, CubeRoot [x] represents x ^ (1/3). How can other Power function be represented correctly in the software?

```
Plot[{x^-1, x^(-1/2), x, CubeRoot[x], x^(1/2), x^(2/3), x^(3/4), x^2, 
  x^3}, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabels -> Automatic, 
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline"]
```

The image x ^ (2/3) drawn in the above code is incorrect

[image]

For example, how can any Power function such as x ^ (2/3), x ^ (6/7), x ^ (3/10), etc. be correctly represented?

Comment: Please put more effort in searching in this site and reading the document: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0VRI.png

Comment: See also this post in Chinese community: https://tieba.baidu.com/p/2113868343

Comment: `Plot[Root[#^3 - x^2 &, 1], {x, -5, 5}]`.